# ¿Cómo ordenar tres div cuadro/marcos?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Me encontré un ejemplo ilustrativo, muy creativo lo he tratado de imitar pero me estoy perdiendo en los estilos `CSS`

> La idea es conseguir el mismo ejemplo de la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo logrado hasta el momento.

Código completo:

```css
#fobd {
margin-top: 70px !important;
margin-bottom: -35px !important;
padding-top: 10px !important;
padding-bottom: 70px !important;
background: #eeeeee url(http://skilled.aislinthemes.com/app/uploads/2015/08/pricing-plans.png?id=10681) !important;
background-position: 0 0 !important;
background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
}
.container {
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}

.center {
text-align: center;
}

.row {
margin-right: -15px;
margin-left: -15px;
}

.four-column {
position: relative;
min-height: 1px;
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
}
.frame-item {
padding: 1em;
border: 1px solid #B2B2B2;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px){
.container {
width: 1170px;
}}
@media (min-width: 992px){
.container {
width: 970px;
}}
@media (min-width: 768px){
.container {
width: 750px;
}}

@media (min-width: 992px){
.four-column {
float: left;
width: 25%;
}}
```

```html
<div id="fobd">
  <div class="container">
  <h2 class="center">CONTACT US</h2>
  </div>
  
  <div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="four-column middle-pro">
    <div class="frame-item">
      <h1>
        Contact US
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="four-column middle-pro">
    <div class="frame-item">
      <h1>
        Contact US
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="four-column middle-pro">
    <div class="frame-item">
      <h1>
        Contact US
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

**¿Ahora mi pregunta?**

Como puedo juntar los 3 cuadros en una sola fila horizontal, tal como muestra la imagen, y al cambiar de dispositivo se realice el responsive ordenadamente.

Comment: Echa un vistazo a Bootstrap y su modelo en columnas http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De hecho ya te lo está haciendo.

La última media query:

```
@media (min-width: 992px){
  .four-column {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
  }
}
```

Es la responsable del cambio. Con resoluciones por encima de 992 pixels te muestra los tres cuadros en horizontal (al asignarle el ancho del 25% a cada uno). En resoluciones por debajo te los muestra uno encima de otro al no aplicarse este estilo.

Si eliminas la media query y aplicas siempre el estilo, siempre se mostrarán distribuidos horizontalmente:

```css
#fobd {
margin-top: 70px !important;
margin-bottom: -35px !important;
padding-top: 10px !important;
padding-bottom: 70px !important;
background: #eeeeee url(http://skilled.aislinthemes.com/app/uploads/2015/08/pricing-plans.png?id=10681) !important;
background-position: 0 0 !important;
background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
}
.container {
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}

.center {
text-align: center;
}

.row {
margin-right: -15px;
margin-left: -15px;
}

.four-column {
position: relative;
min-height: 1px;
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
}
.frame-item {
padding: 1em;
border: 1px solid #B2B2B2;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px){
.container {
width: 1170px;
}}
@media (min-width: 992px){
.container {
width: 970px;
}}
@media (min-width: 768px){
.container {
width: 750px;
}}

.four-column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div id="fobd">
  <div class="container">
  <h2 class="center">CONTACT US</h2>
  </div>
  
  <div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="four-column middle-pro">
    <div class="frame-item">
      <h1>
        Contact US
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="four-column middle-pro">
    <div class="frame-item">
      <h1>
        Contact US
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="four-column middle-pro">
    <div class="frame-item">
      <h1>
        Contact US
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Si deseas que el cambio se realice para otras resoluciones no tienes más que cambiar el valor de min-width en la media query.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas @May,

He tratado de mirar tu código y creo que deberías de usar "flex" en tu css. En 3wschool te dan alguna ayuda de como se usa [CSS flex Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp)

Aquí te dejo tu código un poco modificado, espero haberte ayudado.

```css
#fobd {
margin-top: 70px !important;
margin-bottom: -35px !important;
padding-top: 10px !important;
padding-bottom: 70px !important;
background: #eeeeee url(http://skilled.aislinthemes.com/app/uploads/2015/08/pricing-plans.png?id=10681) !important;
background-position: 0 0 !important;
background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
    display: flex;
    margin: auto;
}

.center {
text-align: center;
}

.four-column {
position: relative;
min-height: 1px;
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
}
.frame-item {
 padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #B2B2B2;
    -webkit-flex: 1;  /* Safari 6.1+ */
    -ms-flex: 1;  /* IE 10 */    
    flex: 1;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px){
.container {
width: 1170px;
}}
@media (min-width: 992px){
.container {
width: 970px;
}}
@media (min-width: 768px){
.container {
width: 750px;
}}

@media (min-width: 992px){
.four-column {
float: left;
width: 25%;
}}
```

```html
<div id="fobd">
  <div class="">
   <h2 class="center">CONTACT US</h2>
  </div>
  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="frame-item">
      <h1>
        Contact US
      </h1>
    </div>

    <div class="frame-item">
      <h1>
        Contact US
      </h1>
    </div>

    <div class="frame-item">
      <h1>
        Contact US
      </h1>
    </div>

  </div>
  
</div>
```